# How to save a pdf to disk using default pdf printer?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to save a pdf file by sending to a default printer and get the saved file name back. Also, it can't display the print dialog. I could not find any example that gives the saved file name.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible, but it may help to know the driver being used for the 'default printer' as different products may act differently. Also, is your application doing the printing of the document - or is it another application?

Comment: I am trying to make it work with "Microsoft Print to PDF" or "CutePDF Writer". It is my application doing the printing. Thank you.